# JSHint, For Loops, Promises and one pesky lint error

Tags: javascript, promise, jshint, lint, rsvp.js

I have a situation in my JavaScript where I'm generating a number of promises which I want to attach `then`/`catch` conditions on to each one to deal with the individual issues.

I'm using the RSVP Promise library which lets me use `allSettled` to determine when all promises have been resolved. RSVP's `allSettled` does give me an evaluation of the output of what succeeded and what failed at the end of all settled promises, but by adding the `then`/`catch` to each Promise I can control better what to do if a particular Promise isn't fulfilled (e.g. prompt user to retry using only those that failed, etc.).

Using my trusty linter (JSHint), I keep getting "`Don't make functions within a loop.`" shouting back at me, and I really want to be able to attach the `then`/`catch` conditions to each Promise without this kind of lint error cropping up.

I'm curious how other people get around the JSHint error regarding this (aside from just changing the JSHint rule. I think it's a good rule!) or if someone has a better idea of how to handle my generated Promises' `then`/`catch` use-case.

Here's an example:

```js
let Promise = RSVP.Promise
let people = ['Marty McFly', 'Doc', 'Robocop', 'Terminator', 'Bozo']
let sendMessagesToPeople = []
let thoseSucceeded = []
let thoseFailed = []

// Dummy Promise method to send a message to a person
function sendMessageToPerson (person, msg) {
  console.log(`Sending message to ${person}...`)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        console.log(`✔︎ Sent "${msg}" to ${person}`)
        resolve(person, msg)
        return
      }
      console.log(`✘ Failed sending "${msg}" to ${person}`)
      reject(person, msg)
    }, 1000 + (Math.random() * 2000))
  })
}

// Generate the array of Promises for allSettled to process
for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  let trySendMessageToPerson = sendMessageToPerson(people[i], "Hi there!")
    /* Illegal, according to JSHint */
    .then(() => {
      thoseSucceeded.push(people[i])
    })
    .catch(() => {
      thoseFailed.push(people[i])
    })

  sendMessagesToPeople.push(trySendMessageToPerson)
}

RSVP.allSettled(sendMessagesToPeople).then(() => {
  console.log(`Succeeded: ${thoseSucceeded.length}, Failed: ${thoseFailed.length}`)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rsvp/3.3.3/rsvp.min.js"></script>
```

***EDIT:***

I was really curious as to the performance differences with `for`, `forEach` and `map` so using the answers given by @rasmeister and @hackerrdave I devised a JSPerf test to try to see which of the loops were more performant (I also threw in a `while` test for fun):
https://jsperf.com/for-foreach-map-while-loop-performance-testing

In my testing the results vary wildly and are very inconclusive, so I have no idea which loop implementation is better performance-wise, but in terms of readability I think I'd have to go for the `map` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let Promise = RSVP.Promise
let people = ['Marty McFly', 'Doc', 'Robocop', 'Terminator', 'Bozo']
let thoseSucceeded = []
let thoseFailed = []

// Dummy Promise method to send a message to a person
function sendMessageToPerson (person, msg) {
  console.log(`Sending message to ${person}...`)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        console.log(`✔︎ Sent "${msg}" to ${person}`)
        resolve(person, msg)
        return
      }
      console.log(`✘ Failed sending "${msg}" to ${person}`)
      reject(person, msg)
    }, 1000 + (Math.random() * 2000))
  })
}

let sendMessagesToPeople = people.map((person) => {
  return sendMessageToPerson(person, "Hi there!")
  .then(() => {
      thoseSucceeded.push(person)
    })
    .catch(() => {
      thoseFailed.push(person)
    })
})

RSVP.allSettled(sendMessagesToPeople).then(() => {
  console.log(`Succeeded: ${thoseSucceeded.length}, Failed: ${thoseFailed.length}`)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rsvp/3.3.3/rsvp.min.js"></script>
```

This would gather up the promises into an array where you can then respond to the m all.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the function definitions from the loop - you can extract all the logic from the loop into one function, then use that in a `forEach`:

```
people.forEach(sendMessage);

function sendMessage(person) {
  let trySendMessageToPerson = sendMessageToPerson(person, "Hi there!")
    .then(thoseSucceded.push)
    .catch(thoseFailed.push);

  sendMessagesToPeople.push(trySendMessageToPerson);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define those two functions which are passed to `then` and `catch` -- and that are now defined in each iteration -- only once:

```
let addSuccess = person => thoseSucceeded.push(person);
let addFailure = person => thoseFailed.push(person);
```

... and then:

```
let trySendMessageToPerson = sendMessageToPerson(people[i], "Hi there!")
    .then(addSuccess)
    .catch(addFailure)
```